# Master environment script based on $LOGNAME to run on any shell invocation

Tags: bash, ssh, cron, environment-variables, login

Dealing with a nice list of Linux (and Solaris) servers, I find that 90% of my users need the same environment variables with a few specifics unique for an individual user.

My goal is to eliminate the need to create a `.profile` for every user and that I could *assume* that an appropriate environment will be sourced by writing/running a master (environment) script that runs the 90% and stipulates then 10% specifics by the value of `$LOGNAME`.

My real question is how can have this master script run on **any shell invocation**

1. Login shell would mostly be `bash`, but I hope to have it for `sh` too.
2. Any subshell
3. Any non-interactive shell
4. `ssh`, **Yes**, I want a remote login from host**A** to host**B**, and be comfy with knowledge that my environment loaded!
5. `sudo su - user`, if I sudo to any user this master env script should run
6. `cron`
7. `at`
8. `batch`
9. What else am I missing? I just want this master env script to run at any which way a shell is invoked.

I started with `$BASH_ENV` per [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html), but that does not work with `ssh`